# Multiple dex files + Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

After searching for similar questions/answers without success I'll try to explain my situation.

I've an Andorid game developed with LibGDX, which also uses the Google Play Games services.

My game is composed by several projects:

1. google-play-services_lib (lib project provided by Google, unmodified)

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XnHn.png (libs)
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gay5H.png (buildpath)
2. BaseGameUtils (lib project provided by Google, unmodified. depends on 1)

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iJ0W.png (libs)
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/noNDX.png (buildpath)
3. odd-blocks (the principal project of the game)

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/atsKA.png (libs)
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MDua.png (buildpath)
4. odd-blocks-android (basically the main activity class, depends on 1, 2, and 3)

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUxJt.png (libs)
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP6wv.png (buildpath)
5. odd-blocks-desktop (for testing the game on desktop mode, depends on 3)

   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKGUf.png (libs)
   - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XzdM.png (buildpath)

My problem is that, with the configuration shown, when I try to execute the odd-blocks-android project I obtain the following error:

```
[2014-03-08 19:04:22 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
[2014-03-08 19:04:22 - odd-blocks-andorid] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
```

Which is related to the "andorid-support-v4.jar", I'm sure to have only one version of this jar, as you can see in the images. There is a "solution" proposed in some questions to disable the private libraries in the build path configuration. In my case, if I do that, the game is executed but before starting there is a exception that says:

```
03-08 18:26:05.524: E/AndroidRuntime(15449): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.damsoft.oddblocks/com.damsoft.oddblocks.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

There are also, some questions available about this second error message, that mentions that it is because the manifest is incorrect because does not have the activity registered. I'm sure that this is not my case, because I checked it, and also because my game worked before. In these questions they also mention that a way to resolve this error is to enable the "android private libraries" in the build path configuration screen, but then, I got the first error...

It is also important to mention that this error started to happen after the update to "Android SDK build-tools" v19 (currently 19.0.3).

I've been trying many things but nothing seems to solve the issue, maybe is something stupid... I don't know, but I'm out of ideas. I hope you can help :)

Comment: I had a similar problem a week ago and in my case the problem was that I was using different paths for android.support.v4. I had more dependencies and some of the projects contained there own android.support.v4 so I had to make sure that all my projects were referring to exactly the same jar.

Comment: I only have one android-support-v4 jar that is referenced in the BaseGameUtils project and then in the android private libs of the "odd-blocks-android" project.

Comment: The last problem I could think of is that you export the android.support.v4 by checking the box (I guess that check means that like on Intellij) from odd-blocks-android and BaseGameUtils depends on it. Try to uncheck android.support.v4 boxes.

Comment: Same problem, cheking or uncheking the android.support.v4 in BaseGameUtils

Comment: Try to uncheck from both projects.

Comment: In the odd-blocks-android the  android.support.v4  itself cannot be uncheck, because it is included indirectly by "Android Private libs", which I can uncheck as a whole, but then I have the second error message.

Comment: Or you could try to delete the android.support.v4 from BaseGameUtils. If this is not working, delete it from "Android Private libs" and add it for each project you need without checking it.

Comment: If I remove android.support.v4  from BaseGameUtils it does not compile, the project needs the lib. Also, I cannot delete individual libs from "Android Private libs" is something that is generated by the android build tools (I guess) and automatically includes the libs of the dependent projects.. well actually I don't know how it works, its just suppositions. But I can only disable it completely or leave as it is.

Comment: I use Intellij and there it lets you delete what is in libs, but it seems that Eclipse is not the same. I'm sorry I couldn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

It was the "gdx-backend-android.jar", and some bad luck.

I installed a nightly build of LibGDX that for some reason included the classes of the android-support-v4.jar that caused the conflict of versions.

My solution was as simple as re-download libgdx.

But as a general remark, it is important to notice that this error message could mean that some other lib includes duplicated classes. Not necessarily with the same file name. The only way I found to check this was to rename the jar files to zip, and check for the duplicated class files.